# display css property does not work on print stylesheet

Tags: html, css, printing

I defined a stylesheet for screen

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="PATH/style.css">
```

and a stylesheet for print

```
<link media="print" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="PATH/printable.css">
```

In style.css there are some items that are not shown

```
#img-sign{
    display:none;
}

.signatures{display:none;}
```

But when I print, I want to display them, so in printable.css

```
#img-sign{
    width:370px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.signatures{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:80px;
}
```

The problem is that these elements will not appear in print.

Here is my HTML code

```
<div id="preview">
    <img src="PATH" id="img-sign" />
    <div class="signatures">
        <div class="profesional-signature">
            <hr>
            Profesional signature
        </div>
        <div class="customer-signature">
            <hr>
            Customer signature
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I change the property `display:none` by `visibility: hidden` and `display:block` by `visibility: visible` everything looks as I want in print but in my web page, there are white areas. 
I've been 2 days with this problem. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your `printable.css` included after `style.css`? Have you tried `display: block;` instead of `display:inline-block;`?

Comment: `printable.css` is included before `style.css` I think that is not important because printable.css has `media="print"` so only is used if the page is printed or am I wrong?. I'm not try `display: block` but why should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

style.css has no media type so it will cover all media types, try adding media="screen" to it and hopefully that should work, if not then you will need to switch the style sheets around